# Convert bytes to a std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

I have a byte array

```
type str_t is array(integer range<>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal rx_uart_buf : str_t(0 to RX_BUF_SIZE-1);
```

I get a number on UART

```
if (rx_rdy3 = '1') then
    if(RX_DATA > X"2F" and RX_DATA < X"3A") then  
        rx_uart_buf(rx_idx) <= RX_DATA - X"30"; --convert to a number
    else
        rx_uart_buf(rx_idx) <= RX_DATA; 
    end if;

        if (rx_idx < RX_BUF_SIZE-1) then
            rx_idx := rx_idx + 1;
        end if;
end if;
```

So if it was sent "1234" I have in the buffer

```
rx_uart_buf(0) - X"01"
rx_uart_buf(1) - X"02"
rx_uart_buf(2) - X"03"
rx_uart_buf(3) - X"04"
```

How I can convert the bytes to std_logic_vector

```
signal reg_data : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := X"0000";
```

To get reg_data - X"1234".

Comment: `reg_data <= rx_uart_buf(0)(3 downto 0) & rx_uart_buf(1)(3 downto 0) & rx_uart_buf(2)(3 downto 0) & rx_uart_buf(3)(3 downto 0);` is this what you are asking?

Comment: You'd also find you don't need to subtract x"30" from RX_DATA. The 4 LSBs don't change.

Comment: but it should be generic ;)

Comment: what if I'll get 123 or 12345?

Comment: If you're trying to add caveats to your question in comments your question is unclear and could likely benefit from a code example approaching a [mcve]. Here imagine in response to "but it should be generic" someone were to ask what it were you referring to, and for "what if ..." commented you weren't being specific. The quality of an answer is predicated on the quality of a question, the quality of both controlling their usefulness to future readers.

Comment: I get different numbers - so conversion has to be generic- what is so unclear and what caveats has you seen?

Comment: It's not an academic question. I need it to use in practice in the real code. And I'm very grateful for the answer provided by  Giampietro Seu.

Comment: By the way                                                                                                 reg_data <= rx_uart_buf(0)(3 downto 0) & rx_uart_buf(1)(3 downto 0) & rx_uart_buf(2)(3 downto 0) & rx_uart_buf(3)(3 downto 0);  It works only with hex numbers. And I get numbers in decimal form - 1234 not 0x04D2.

Answer (score 1):

As other people said, your question is incomplete and does not have a [minimal reproductible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In other word, it is hard to help you.

From point of view, from each bytes in `rx_uart_buf`, you are taking the 4 lowest significant bits and assignig them into a part of `reg_data`. You are NOT writing the all byte into `reg_data` !

To perform this, I am using a `for loop`: [some explanation about the for loop here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/for_loop.html)

```
optional_label: for parameter in range loop
    sequential statements
end loop label;
```

It gives me:

```
--a for loop that assign the first 4 less significant bits of each bytes of rx_uart_buf into reg_data.
            conversion : for i in rx_uart_buf'reverse_range loop
                reg_data(i*4+3 downto i*4) <= rx_uart_buf(i)(3 downto 0);
            end loop;
```

I have therefore produce my own code doing what you are looking for. It is for simulation purpose.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL; 


entity test_bytes is

end entity;


architecture Behavioral of test_bytes is

    signal   clk         : std_logic := '1';    --the clock (not used, only to see it in the simulation waves)
    constant period      : time := 8us;         --the clock period
    constant half_period : time := 4us;         --the half period of the clock

    --the variables you have in your code
    constant RX_BUF_SIZE : integer := 4;
    type str_t is array(integer range<>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal rx_uart_buf : str_t(0 to RX_BUF_SIZE-1) := (0 => X"00", 1 => X"00", 2 => X"00", 3 => X"00");
    signal reg_data : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := X"0000";

begin

    --the generation of the clock
    clk <= not clk after half_period;


    --a process that convert the first 4 less significant bits of each bytes of rx_uart_buf into reg_data.
    --it is for simulation purpose, everything might not be synthetisable.
    process_conversion : process

        --a procedure that does the function you are looking for
        procedure conversion_buffer is
        begin
            --a for loop that assign the first 4 less significant bits of each bytes of rx_uart_buf into reg_data.
            conversion : for i in rx_uart_buf'reverse_range loop
                reg_data(i*4+3 downto i*4) <= rx_uart_buf(i)(3 downto 0);
            end loop;
        end procedure;

    begin
        wait for 2*period;

        --we have some values in our buffer
        rx_uart_buf <= (0 => X"01", 1 => X"02", 2 => X"03", 3 => X"04");
        reg_data <= X"0000";
        wait for 1*period;
        --we assign the values into the new signal
        conversion_buffer;
        wait for 2*period;

        --we have some values in our buffer
        rx_uart_buf <= (0 => X"0f", 1 => X"0e", 2 => X"0d", 3 => X"0c");
        reg_data <= X"0000";
        wait for 1*period;
        --we assign the values into the new signal
        conversion_buffer;
        wait for 2*period;

        --we have some values in our buffer
        rx_uart_buf <= (0 => X"10", 1 => X"20", 2 => X"30", 3 => X"40");
        reg_data <= X"0000";
        wait for 1*period;
        --we assign the values into the new signal
        conversion_buffer;
        wait for 2*period;

        --we have some values in our buffer
        rx_uart_buf <= (0 => X"f1", 1 => X"a2", 2 => X"0d", 3 => X"45");
        reg_data <= X"0000";
        wait for 1*period;
        --we assign the values into the new signal
        conversion_buffer;

        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

If you need other informations, you can edit your post.